# Render date field in custom format in tpl file

Tags: 7, theming

In a content type tpl file I can print my date field with the following:

```
<?php print render($content['my_date_field']); ?>
```

However I need a custom date format. So instead of something like this:
Sunday, June 9, 2013 - 16:50

I need to print:
June 9th Sunday

I cant change the default date formats site wide or the node's field, I need to just modify how its printed in this instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive solved it a different way. Ive created a custom date format and I can chose that as the display option for the field for a specific view mode.

/admin/config/regional/date-time/formats